# Data that gave no output

Tags: sql

I have an input table in an Oracle Database that feeds a list of VINs to another query that generates data. However, I want to be able to say no data for the inputs that did not generate an output. Is there a way I can do this in an Oracle SQL query?
EDIT: There is only one table. The input table

INPUT:

```
VIN
123456
678901
123432
```

OUTPUT: This is the output of a SELECT query.

```
VIN     OPTION
123456   ABC
678901   DEF
```

NEEDED OUTPUT: Need this output from one SELECT statement using the input from input table.

```
VIN      OPTION
123456    ABC
678901    DEF
123432    NO DATA
```

Comment: Looks like an INNER JOIN is being done. You can try replacing that with a LEFT JOIN and then replace the nulls with "NO DATA"

Answer (score 0):

This is what a left join is for:

```
SELECT i.VIN, COALESCE(o.option, 'NO DATA') as option
FROM 
  input i 
  LEFT JOIN output o ON i.vin = o.vin
```

If an inner join is used then the missing row in Output causes the entire result row to disappear. With a left join the table on the left (called Input in your case) is treated as the "authority" - all of its rows will be present in the results. Rows in output that match will be in the results too but critically a missing row in output will not cause the result row to disappear. Instead there will be NULL in all the columns from Output for that row

It's important to point out that you might have a row in Output that has a VIN but has a null option. If you want to detect this situation consider the following:

```
SELECT 
  i.VIN, 
  CASE 
    WHEN o.vin IS NULL THEN 'there is no output row for this input' 
    WHEN o.option IS NULL THEN 'there is an output row for this input vin but the value of Option in the row, is null'
    ELSE o.option
  END as option
FROM 
  input i 
  LEFT JOIN output o ON i.vin = o.vin
```

Comment: Hi, I am sorry I think the description may not have been clear. But there is only one table that is the input. I take the input and run a select statement. The output of this select statement is not stored in a table.

Comment: Post the select statement